# Cheezy Page-Object Gem Dynamic Locator for Generic Element?

Tags: ruby, watir, page-object-gem

Using Cheezy's page-object gem I've come across the ability to have dynamic element locators. (Noted at this github issue: https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/203).

So for example I can do `span_element(id: 'some id')`, `div_element(class: 'some_class')`, etc. However what can I do if I need to locate a generic element? For example I could be working on a page that has angular so the elements are not traditional (like instead of a traditional html select control with options, it is a custom angular dropdown). I've tried `element_element(class: 'class_name')` and just `element(class: 'class_name')` but ruby says `method missing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic dynamic element locator is defined in [PageObject::ElementLocators#element](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/49a80488bfc9647f3869df53e06fabb9623caad2/lib/page-object/element_locators.rb) as:

```
def element(tag, identifier={:index => 0})
  platform.element_for(tag, identifier.clone)
end
```

The first argument is the element's tag name. If you don't know the tag name, you can specify "element" for any tag. For example:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  def do_stuff
    element('element', class: 'class_name').text
  end
end
```

Comment: This isn't very ideal, so I created a feature request to make the tag name optional - https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/491

Comment: Hi, I think Cheezy is not maintaining the gem now. Can't you branch out and maintain by yourself ?

Comment: Oh you are committer there too?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, I have commit access to Page-Object, but not permission to publish the gem (Cheezy does that as necessary). I'm trying to find time to maintain this gem as well as Watir.

Comment: Oh okay. So even if you commit, he has to publish the next version for your new commit available to people . So it's once again seems like not useful. He will do anytime soon?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, I don't see the problem. Cheezy has been quite available for publishing the gem. It's a problem of either of us having time to actually do the development. If there was something completely broken with Page-Object, I'm sure one of us would find the time to fix it. But at this point, given it's all feature requests or making it better, it's harder to find the time. But like I said, I am trying to get more into it these days. Hopefully there will be success.